# Creating multilanguage homepage

Tags: php

so im making homepage with three languages.
I am using switch method, here is code -

```
  public function languages()
{
if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != '')
{
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
else
{
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en_EN';
}
switch($_SESSION['lang'])
{
  case 'en_EN': require_once('language/lang.eng.php');break;
  case 'lv_LV': require_once('language/lang.lv.php');break;
  case 'ru_RU': require_once('language/lang.ru.php');break;
  default: require_once('language/lang.eng.php');
}
}

public function translate($txt)
{
  global $text;
  return $text[$txt];
}
```

and it should display in index.php file like this -

```
<?php $index->translate('search'); ?>
```

but the problem is that it shows no errors, no notices, no warnings and no translated or default text.
I included function languages() , maybe you can help me with this problem?

EDIT: 
im calling $language at start of index.php file - `<?php require_once('class.index.php'); $index = new index; $index->languages(); ?>` and $text is defined in lang.eng.php; lang.lv.php and lang.ru.php file.

Comment: are you calling languages() before translate()? Are they class methods, right?

Comment: You defined `languages()` but I don't see where you're calling it. Also, where is `$text` defined?

Comment: Hello,
im calling $language at start of index.php file - 
<?php require_once('class.index.php');
$index = new index;
$index->languages(); 
?> and $text is defined in lang.eng.php; lang.lv.php and lang.ru.php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a class, I think it's better to use properties instead of globals, it will be easier in future mantainance. Create a class variable holding $text and use that

```
class Index {

  var $text;

  public function languages()
  {
    require(".....");

    $this->text = $text;
  }

  public function translate($txt)
  {
    if(isset($this->text[$txt]))
    {
      return $this->text[$txt];
    }
    else
    {
     return "no translation";
    }
  }

}

$index = new Index;
$index->languages();
echo $index->translate('search');
```

Comment: Hey, hmm, my language file looks like this - 
$text = array(
'search' => 'Search',
'read_more' => 'Read more',
(here are more translations...)
);
I got question, what i must put inside require?
WHOORAY it works ;)!
Cheers :)

Comment: ...Ok, so what's wrong with my code? if you pass 'search', it searches for the key 'search' in your array, if exists, returns it. I just added some default message, you can skip that part if it bothers you!

Comment: oh, ok :) I just didn't copy all your text, those where just ellipsis. Glad everything works ;). If this answers your question, please mark the answer as "accepted", thank you!

Comment: Hmm, i think i pressed accepted, not sure, but if i didnt, just tell me ill search for other accept buttons :). Thank you again :)!

Comment: You did great, don't worry! thanks! good luck with the project!cheers

Answer (score 1):

type

```
<?php echo $index->translate('search'); ?>
```

Comment: I got it there, just rewrited it here, and forgot to add, mistake :(. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check first whether the session is initialized or not and also place the languages() function call before the translate so that it loads the language prior to translation and also put error_reporting(E_ALL) at top so that any error suppresion will be be removed and also put echo the returned result of translate statement

Comment: Hello, if i echo $_SESSION['lang'] it shows everything correctly, with error_reporting, it shows no errors (got it already on e_ALL), and i got it there, just rewrited it here, and forgot to add, mistake :(. Any other suggestions?